# new operator -> with or without

Tags: c++, oop, new-operator

## Objective

Trying to learn the difference in behavior of instantiating derived class objects

#### My work

1. Created a class "person"
2. Added a virtual method to "person" class that sets value to variable ***name***
3. Defined a class "employee" derived from the base class "person"
4. Added a method to "employee" class that sets value to variable ***name*** initially defined in the base class but adds "さん" suffix after it.
5. Created different types or initiations and tested the difference between the outputs

#### Defined classes

> I created a base class "person" and a derived class "employee" as below

**person**

```
class person
{
protected:
    string name;
public:
    person();
    ~person();

    virtual void setName(string myName)
    {
        name = myName;
    }
};
```

**employee**

```
class employee :    public person
{
public:
    employee();
    ~employee();
    void setName(string myName)
    {
        name = myName+"さん";
    }
};
```

#### Main

```
int main()
{
    person newPerson = person();

    employee anotherPerson1 = employee();

    employee* anotherPerson2 = new employee();

    person extraPerson1 = employee();

    person* extraPerson2 = new employee();

    newPerson.setName("new");   
    anotherPerson1.setName("another1");
    anotherPerson2->setName("another2");
    extraPerson1.setName("extra1");
    extraPerson2->setName("extra2");


    cout << newPerson.getName() << endl;
    cout << anotherPerson1.getName() << endl;
    cout << anotherPerson2->getName() << endl;
    cout << extraPerson1.getName() << endl;
    cout << extraPerson2->getName();
}
```

#### Console output

```
new
another1さん
another2さん
extra1
extra2さん
```

#### Question

I understand the behavior of newPerson, anotherPerson1 and anotherPerson2.

> I fail to understand why extraPerson1 and extraPerson2 behave differently even though both seem to have similar initiations.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
person extraPerson1 = employee();
```

you [*slice*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) the `employee` object into a `person` object. The object `extraPerson1` is a `person` object and not an `employee` object. When you call its `setName` function you're calling `person::setName`.

Polymorphism and virtual functions only work if you have *pointers* or *references*.